# I do not understand the args() in R programming

Tags: r

I do not understand args() in R programming. For example, args(list.files) returns some gibberish:

```
args(list.files)
#function (path = ".", pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE, full.names = FALSE, 
#    recursive = FALSE, ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, 
#    no.. = FALSE) 
#NULL
```

Comment: From `help('args')`, section Description: `Displays the argument names and corresponding default values of a function or primitive.` Is this clear?

Answer (score 2):

Explanation about **args()**

So args() is itself function which is used to display arguments for corresponding function that is passed to it.

ex. you want to learn about list.files parameters so you pass that into **args()** like **args(list.files)** and it will result in output you specified.

Please read the documentation about **args** here https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/args

Please read the documentation about **list.files** here https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/list.files